# React CSS Transition to change visible component with onClick through state

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, reactcsstransitiongroup

I don't understand whats wrong here, I've done this before and I'm sure this is the way. I even copy and pasted two separate examples. Just trying to get the CSS transition Group going so that when a button is clicked and the state changes, the right component appears but with an effect. I'm getting nothing

The component showing depends on the state value: 1, 2 or 3. I just want for when that state changes and another component is being displayed rather than the one before for there to be an animation to make one leave and another arrive

Whatever visible component there is it is clear that there is a way to navigate back and forth between options as the each are sent an onClick method to change the state of the class

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

class LoginClass extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {loginCompState: 0};

        this.showInitial = this.showInitial.bind(this);
        this.showPro = this.showPro.bind(this);
        this.showUser = this.showUser.bind(this);
    }

    showPro(){
      this.setState({
        loginCompState: 1
      });
    };

    showUser(){
      this.setState({
        loginCompState: 2
      });
    };

    showInitial(){
      this.setState({
        loginCompState: 0
      });
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                    transitionName='fade'
                    transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                    transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                    {(this.state.loginCompState === 0) ? 
                            <InitialComp proOnClick={this.showPro} userOnClick={this.showUser} /> : 
                            (this.state.loginCompState === 1) ? 
                                <ProLoginChoices backInitial={this.showInitial} /> : 
                                <UserLoginChoices backInitial={this.showInitial} />} 
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

accompanying CSS:

```
.fade-enter {
    right: 100px;
}

/* End State of Animation */
.fade-enter-active {
    right: 0px;
    transition: .5s ease-in all;
}
```

Comment: can you make a simple fiddle?

Comment: Is there any question you have that can't be answered above? I tried making a fiddle but it seems the react on fiddle hasn't been updated and gave me errors I don't understand